# How to fix eslint error when using the node: protocol when importing Node.js builtin modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocols, eslint

Please, direct me what should I write in `.eslintrc` in my situation.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38343
https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-node-protocol.md

If I deny this rule I got error:

```js
import path from "path"; // ESLint: Prefer `node:path` over `path`.(unicorn/prefer-node-protocol)
```

Else I got this error:

```js
import path from "node:path"; // ESLint: Unable to resolve path to module 'node:path'.(import/no-unresolved)
```

I want to use both of rules. But I can't imagine what to write down for linter to understand that `node:path` is just about the same as `path`.
Node environment is enabled for this file:

```json
"env": {
  "node": true
}
```

`node -v -> v14.16.1`

Comment: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/2035#issuecomment-826356263

Comment: For the moment just disabled this rule: `'unicorn/prefer-node-protocol': 0`

Comment: This problem is related to node (and its typings). It seems that they have recently removed support for node: protocol https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/52595

Answer (score 5):

Currently you need node 16 to use the "node:" prefix.

Support will be backported to node 14 and 12 but (at the time of writing this) these backports haven't been released yet.

Node 14.18.0 should include the backport ([looking at this commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/7af8896d99f5e61704c887c993ec2e8446f390ad)).